# Describe the conjugacy classes of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Describe the conjugacy classes of an abelian group.

Each class is singleton set as for an abelian group $ax=xa$ $\forall x, a \in G$ which gives $xax^{-1}=a$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes (you probably meant to describe the conjugacy classes, rather than just the conjugacy class, as it will usually have more than one)

Answer (score 6):

Noting to say more than @Tobias's comment for your problem. Just noting that if we set $$\Delta(x)=\{x^g\mid g\in G\}=\{g^{-1}xg\mid g\in G\}$$ then we can see that $|\Delta(x)|=|G:C_G(x)|$ and since $G$ is abelian so every conjugacy classes is singleton
.

Comment: $+1$, dear friend!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$